# Failing to get response from get request

Tags: c#, rest, async-await, httpresponse

so I'm really rusty with C#. I'm trying to do a GET http request, but my responses always are just blank/null. Here's my code

```
    class ServerUtil
{
    String status = "";
    public String serverMessage(String query)
    {
        serverMessageHelper(query);
        return status;
    }

    private async void serverMessageHelper(String query)
    {
        UriBuilder baseUri = new UriBuilder("http://darksync-anarchysystems.rhcloud.com/ServletExample/ServletExample?");
        baseUri.Query = baseUri.Query.Substring(1) + query;
        string url = baseUri.Uri.ToString();
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

        try
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            status = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        catch
        {
            status = "505";
        }
    }


}
```

I create a ServerUtil object, and do the server call as such in code

```
ServerUtil s = new ServerUtil();
string resp = s.serverMessage("action=login&user=" + username + "&password=" + password);
```

The weird thing is that it makes changes in my server, but no response..

Comment: This might not be relevant to your issue, but you shouldn't use `async void`, use `async Task` instead.

Comment: How would I code it so the method can return the response though? If it is async Task then there needs to be an await on calling the helper method, then my main method can't do a return..

Comment: If you don't want the `serverMessage` to be asynchronous, then simply invoke `Wait()` on the returned task from `serverMessageHelper`. However, you should really consider making your code asynchronous all the way. See [this reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the following and get a status response correctly.

```
class ServerUtil
{
    public string ServerMessage(string query)
    {
        return ServerMessageHelperAsync(query).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
    public async Task<string> ServerMessageAsync(string query)
    {
        return await ServerMessageHelperAsync(query);
    }

    private async Task<string> ServerMessageHelperAsync(string query)
    {
        var baseUri = new UriBuilder("http://darksync-anarchysystems.rhcloud.com/ServletExample/ServletExample");
        baseUri.Query = query;
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()))
        {
            try
            {
                using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(baseUri.Uri).ConfigureAwait(false))
                {
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return "505";
            }
        }
    }

}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var username = "xxx";
        var password = "xxx";
        var s = new ServerUtil();
        //var resp = s.ServerMessageAsync("action=login&user=" + username + "&password=" + password).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        var resp = s.ServerMessage("action=login&user=" + username + "&password=" + password);
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason my program freezes* on any server call now. It seems like it is constantly waiting for the response, not sure why, I copied your code exactly, and the url that it is creating works fine in the browser.

Comment: Where is it "freezing"?

Comment: I fixed it by adding .ConfigureAwait(false) after GetAsync(baseUri.Uri)